# ClickOnce and autoupdates

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, clickonce, auto-update

I've deployed app to the server with autoupdates before app is launch enabled

```
<subscription>
  <update>
     <beforeApplicationStartup />
  </update>
</subscription>
```

and I installed this app on the other machine. But when I do some changes to the project and republish it to the same server, installed app on the other machine doesn't see updates and running older version. I'm increasing revision number in every republish. Why does not that app see an update?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many things you cancheck.

- Application should check for updates (Properties in Publish Tab)
- When publishing a new version, you have to increment the version (from 1.0.0.0 to 1.0.0.1)
- Update location (URL or UNC pat) have to be accessible for application